# gIntersects with large spatial data

Tags: r, rgeos

I am using the `gIntersects` function from the rgeos package to check whether a river layer (polyline) intersects with a species maps (polygons). However, it is taking ages to do the calculations, despite I have simplified the layers with `gSimplify` and added `prepared=TRUE` to the function formula. Is there any way to improve the speed of the process?

Comment: Probably the best speed up is to migrate to using `sf` package instead of `sp`/`rgeos`. You can convert the objects with `st_as_sf`. The analogous function is sf::st_intersects

Comment: it seems that st_as_sf turns my files into tables, can I still do the sf_intersects with them? they have the coordinates in a column, but I don´t know if the program detects them as coordinates

Comment: You can, it's like sp but a bit different. See the sf vignettes for an overview. (The sp objects behaved mostly *as-if* they were data frames, but they weren't. The sf objects *are* data frames. )

Comment: @Imanol Miqueleiz, did moving from `sp` to `sf` package functionality as @mdsumner suggested bring any improvement? I didn't find `sf::st_intersects` faster than `rgeos::gIntersects` so far. Maybe the only way to speed thing up would be executing things in parallel, e.g. [foreach](http://bgc.yale.edu/sites/default/files/ParallelR.html) . Also, `prepared=TRUE` is the default in `gIntersects`, so no need to add it.